# Java: Trouble understanding XML DOM Parser Code

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I don't know why but I am having a really difficult time understanding XML DOM Parsing and was wondering if someone could help me understand the code. Currently I have the following XML file contents:

```
<environment>
  <gravity direction="90" magnitude="20"/>
  <viscosity magnitude="0.8"/>
  <centermass magnitude="100" exponent="2.0"/>
  <wall id="1" magnitude="40" exponent="1.5"/>
  <wall id="2" magnitude="50" exponent="2.0"/>
  <wall id="3" magnitude="180" exponent="1.0"/>
  <wall id="4" magnitude="10" exponent="0.0"/>
</environment>
```

Here is the Java class I have compiled from different tutorials, but I get stuck when trying to extract values from the individual nodes like gravity, viscosity, etc.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.io.*;

public class XMLParser{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            File environment = new File("environment.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(environment);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("environment");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodes.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element = (Element) node;

// I don't think I need to loop through nodes because I only have one environment node, but I've kept it there to deal with general cases. Then node contains the child nodes I would like to extract data from, such as gravity, viscosity, etc, but I'm not sure quite how to do it. 
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Sorry for the long post and thanks for helping out!

Comment: Lol i happened to be writing something similar when you posted this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the one node you will be looking at in your loop will be the root element node. Iterate through its child nodes and they will be the actual nodes you are interested in. You can do this as you have done to get to the root element. Also you can google a tutorial on this very easily:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for the reference. I think it makes slightly more sense now. One question for the following line of code,

`System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));`


the tutorial extracted only one attribute. If I wanted to extract more than one attribute, how would I go about doing that? I know there's a method .getAttributes() but it returns a NamedNodeMap and there doesn't seem to be an option for me to specify the name of the element that there are more than one elements for:

Comment: Same thing just pass the value of the attribue you are interested in. ie element.getAttribute("magnitude")

Comment: YES I FIGURED IT OUT! <3

Comment: good to hear. Also be thankful you dont have to produce the xml you parse via VB6 from CorelDraw, its balls

Answer (score 0):

1 First you are reading xml file

2 Call DOM parser that creates in memmory structure from Elements that coresponds to your xml

3 Getting root element

4 Iterate childrens of root element

Thats all